# How to send a message inside a docker container to outside Rabbitmq broker?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

We have a RabbitMQ broker running on one of our servers. I've created a docker container in which messages are sent to the broker.

I've run the container with "-p 5672:5672" so the messages from the broker into the container is working. I mean the messages from the broker can be received in the container.

However, the message from the container cannot be delivered to the broker. I can see from the log the below:

```
conn=<SelectConnection OPEN socket=('172.17.0.2', 46992)->('128.xx.xxx.50', 5672)
```

I tried to expose some ranges of ports in the container but it did not work.

How can I send messages from a docker container to outside RabbitMQ broker? BTW, I am using pika 0.12.0.

Thanks,
Seung

Comment: use --net=host with docker run and dont expose any ports

Comment: Well, thanks for the info. But still cannot send messages from the container.